# How is 0 = infinite from infinite series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The infinite series $1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ... = 1$
made me get $$(1-a)+a(1-a)+a^2(1-a)+...=1$$
by dividing both sides with $(1-a)$
I get $1+a+a^2+a^3+...=\frac{1}{(1-a)}$
where $a\neq1$

However, when $$\lim_{a\to 1}1+a+a^2+a^3+...=\frac{1}{(1-a)}$$ the L.H.S. of the equation will be infinite and R.H.S. will be $0$.

Why is this possible ? Did I made calculation mistakes somewhere ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Are you saying that $\lim_{a\to1}\frac1{1-a}=0$?

Comment: How does the right-hand side become $0$?

The limit $\lim_{a\to 1^-} 1/(1-a) $ tends to infinity.

Comment: $$\dfrac1{1-1^-}=\infty.$$

Comment: I am sorry that I did not check carefully.
Thank you for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The R.H.S won't be zero since $lim_{a→1}\frac{1}{1-a}$ doesn't exist (if you compute the limits for $a→1^{+}$ and $a→1^{-}$ you get $-\infty$ and $+\infty$ respectively). Moreover $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}r^{n}=\frac{1}{1-r}$ converges only when $|r|<1$.

Comment: I think you mean $a \rightarrow 1^{+}$ and $a \rightarrow 1^{-}$.

Comment: Yes corrected it, thank you.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the limit of the series is $\infty$, as it is undefined on the right, unlike the function $\frac1{1-a}$.

Answer (score 0):

For $|a|<1$,

$$S(a):=1+a+a^2+a^3+\cdots$$

does converge to $$\frac1{1-a}$$ because the terms decrease fast enough (exponentially).

For $|a|\ge1$, the series diverges as the terms do not tend to $0$, and $S(a)$ is undefined.

So we do have

$$\lim_{a\to1}S(a)=\infty.$$

---

**Caution:**

By contrast, $$\lim_{a\to1}\frac1{1-a}$$ does not exist. The two functions don't have the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

You *don't* get
$$
1+a+a^2+\dotsb = \frac{1}{1-a}
$$
when $a\ne1$, but only when $|a|<1$. A *necessary* condition for convergence of the series in the left-hand side is that the general term has limit zero, which is false for $|a|\ge1$.

For $|a|<1$ the series actually converges. And there is no contradiction, because for $a\to1^-$, the limit of the series is $\infty$ and the same is for the limit of the right-hand side, because they're exactly the same function.

---

You might think to adjust your example by using $a=2$; then the series at the left-hand side diverges to $\infty$ and the right-hand side is $-1$. Is this a contradiction? No. The series doesn't converge, so its sum is not the same as $1/(1-a)$ when $|a|\ge1$.